# How to remove double quotes from a middle of a word in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string which is input characters entered in a textbox- **Hello" How are you.**
Now i want the double quotes which have been introduced in the middle to be removed so that i get the final string as - Hello How are you

The below is what i have tried so far.

```
   <script>
 function myFunction() {
  var str = 'Hello" How are you';
  var patt = /[a-zA-Z0-9-.{}@!#$%&()":,?=+_-~?\s]/g; // describes all the special characters which are allowed.

  var result = str.match(patt);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
 }
</script>
```

Request anyone here to help me on this.

Comment: This is a syntax error unless you escape the quote after "Hello": `"Hello\" How are you";`

Comment: but the input string here i am directly taking from the text box, i dont have the control to escape the quote.

Comment: `match()` returns array or null. You stated what you tried but not what is wrong with it

Comment: if you simply want to remove the `"` that comes as value from an input, maybe `str = str.replace(/"/g,"")` should help

Comment: `str = "Hello" How are you" ` this will give **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** . Better to have a validation check to remove the extra double quote before submitting or coming out of textbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method on the input string with a regular expression to remove the double quotes in that string.

> the `g` flag (global) is used to replace all the occurrences of the `"` in the string. Without it, it will replace the **first** occurrence **only**.

```js
const str = 'Hello" How are" you',
  regex = /"/g; /** "g" flag is used, you remove it to only replace first occurrence **/

console.log(str.replace(regex, ''));
```

**EDIT :**

You said that the input string is taken from an `input` field, here's a demo to print the updated (having `"` removed if found) value from a field to a `div` :

```js
const inp = document.getElementById('input'),
  outputDefault = document.getElementById('output-default'),
  output = document.getElementById('output'),
  regex = /"/g;

inp.addEventListener('input', () => {
  /** the text typed as it is without no replacing **/
  outputDefault.textContent = inp.value;

  /** the text with replacing **/
  output.textContent = inp.value.replace(regex, '')
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<div>the value typed as it is : <span id="output-default"></span></div>
<div>the value gets updated while you type : <span id="output"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function:

```
var result = str.replace(/"/g,'');
```

Comment: like this you'll remove only first occurrence.

Comment: added global flag. Thx @ths

Answer (score 0):

```
const stripQuotes = val => val.replace(/"/g, "");

stripQuotes("your textfields value");
```

Here's a working sample: https://jsbin.com/suvamufabi/1/edit?js,console,output